# Scaling \ddots in smallmatrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices, mathtools

I'm trying visualize a very large matrix. To do so, I'm trying to use `\vdots` and `\ddots` in a `bsmallmatrix` enviroment. It works but they do not scale properly as `\cdots` do. 
Now, in the minimal reproducible example below, I have found a fix [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/1gDD_HIe9r0) which works, but *only* the vertical dots and not the diagonal dots.
I do not understand why it does not work for `\ddots`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\svdots}{\raisebox{3pt}{\scalebox{.75}{\vdots}}} % <- Works
\newcommand{\sddots}{\raisebox{3pt}{\scalebox{.75}{\ddots}}} % <- Do not work

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bsmallmatrix}
    a_{11}  & a_{12}  & \cdots  & a_{1m}  \\
    a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \cdots  & a_{2m}  \\
    \svdots & \svdots & \sddots & \svdots \\
    a_{n1}  & a_{n2}  & \cdots  & a_{nm}
  \end{bsmallmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The compilation errors revolves around missing `$` and brackets.
The document complies fine when substituting `\sddots` for `\ddots` but, obviously, the ddots have the wrong size.

How do I best accomplish my desired result?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: the version in the answer you reverence has `$` to put the dots in math mode but you have omitted them here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed I have, adding them around the `\scalebox` makes no difference. `\svdots` still works fine, but `\sddots` does not.

Comment: You have to say `\scalebox{.75}{$\ddots$}`; it's not really needed for `\vdots`, but it's better to add `$` also around it, for consistency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following example redefines `\vdots` and `\ddots` to get a resizable version according to the current math style. The vertical space between the dots is taken from the horizontal dots. Also the dots in `\ddots` match the vertical spacing of `\vdots` and the horizontal spacing of the horizontal dots in `\cdots`. `\cdots` adds a thin space at the right side. For a better alignment in matrices, the redefined `\ddots` also adds this space.

The space above `\vdots` and `\ddots` is not fixed, the space between the dots is used for the additional vertical space above the symbol. It's a tiny bit smaller in `\textstyle` and `\displaystyle` than the original symbols, but the resizing in `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` is much better as the `bsmallmatrix` example shows.

The following example shows the `bsmallmatrix` with the resizable dots.
Then a normal `bmatrix` follows to show the symbols in the normal larger style. Then the `bmatrix` follows with the original `\vdots` and `\ddots`, saved in `\orgvdots` and `\orgddots`.

At the end of the example, the bounding boxes for the symbols in the different math styles are shown, first the original symbols, then the redefined symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\orgvdots\vdots
\LetLtxMacro\orgddots\ddots

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\vdots{%
  \mathpalette\@vdots{}%
}
\newcommand*{\@vdots}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\cdotp\cdotp\cdotp\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#1.\m@th$}%
  \vbox{%
    \dimen@=\wd0 %
    \advance\dimen@ -3\ht2 %
    \kern.5\dimen@
    % remove side bearings
    \dimen@=\wd2 %
    \advance\dimen@ -\ht2 %
    \dimen2=\wd0 %
    \advance\dimen2 -\dimen@
    \vbox to \dimen2{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \copy2 \vfill\copy2 \vfill\copy2 %
    }%
  }%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\ddots{%
  \mathinner{%
    \mathpalette\@ddots{}%
    \mkern\thinmuskip
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@ddots}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\cdotp\cdotp\cdotp\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#1.\m@th$}%
  \vbox{%
    \dimen@=\wd0 %
    \advance\dimen@ -3\ht2 %
    \kern.5\dimen@
    % remove side bearings
    \dimen@=\wd2 %
    \advance\dimen@ -\ht2 %
    \dimen2=\wd0 %
    \advance\dimen2 -\dimen@
    \vbox to \dimen2{%
      \offinterlineskip
      \hbox{$#1\mathpunct{.}\m@th$}%
      \vfill
      \hbox{$#1\mathpunct{\kern\wd2}\mathpunct{.}\m@th$}%
      \vfill
      \hbox{$#1\mathpunct{\kern\wd2}\mathpunct{\kern\wd2}\mathpunct{.}\m@th$}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  \begin{bsmallmatrix}
    a_{11}  & a_{12}  & \cdots  & a_{1m}  \\
    a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \cdots  & a_{2m}  \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{n1}  & a_{n2}  & \cdots  & a_{nm}
  \end{bsmallmatrix}
\\
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}  & a_{12}  & \cdots  & a_{1m}  \\
    a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \cdots  & a_{2m}  \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{n1}  & a_{n2}  & \cdots  & a_{nm}
  \end{bmatrix}
\\
  \begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11}  & a_{12}  & \cdots  & a_{1m}  \\
    a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \cdots  & a_{2m}  \\
    \orgvdots & \orgvdots & \orgddots & \orgvdots \\
    a_{n1}  & a_{n2}  & \cdots  & a_{nm}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather*}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}

\newcommand*{\test}[1]{%
  \fbox{$#1\orgvdots$}%
  \fbox{$#1\orgddots$}%
  \fbox{$#1\vdots$}%
  \fbox{$#1\ddots$}%
  \fbox{$#1\dots$}%
  \fbox{$#1\cdots$}%
  \fbox{$#1\cdotp\cdotp\cdotp$}%
}
\begin{gather*}
  \test{}\\
  \test{\scriptstyle}\\
  \test{\scriptscriptstyle}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: There’s one thing I don’t understand in your code: since there are _three_ dots in `\box0`, shouldn’t it be `\advance\dimen@ -3\ht2 ` instead of `\advance\dimen@ -2\ht2 `?  As I understand it, your intention is to leave in `\dimen@` the dimension of the total space between the dots — there are two spaces, so you subsequently `\kern` by half this amount.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti You are right, it should be 3, answer updated.

Comment: Just another little thing, _if_ I’m not abusing your patience: `\cdotp` is a `\mathpunct`, so we know from the table on page 170 what the space between the dots is going to be; therefore, instead of the slightly obscure computation, couldn’t one say something like `\sbox4{$#1\nonscript\,\m@th$}` followed by `\kern\wd4`?  Please don’t even think that I dare tut-tut Heiko Oberdiek from the bottom of my 560 reputation: indeed, I’ve been long in doubt whether to post this rather punctilious comment, although, as you can see, in the end I couldn’t resist… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti There are many ways of doing the calculations. I had put `\cdotp` inside box 0 (a) to avoid the calculation of the width manually and (b) to catch the cases script and non-script styles. The space between punctuation atoms is only set in non-script styles.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing one additional`$...$` pair:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\svdots}{\raisebox{3pt}{$\scalebox{.75}{\vdots}$}} % <- Works
\newcommand{\sddots}{\raisebox{3pt}{$\scalebox{.75}{$\ddots$}$}} % <- Do not work

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bsmallmatrix}
    a_{11}  & a_{12}  & \cdots  & a_{1m}  \\
    a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \cdots  & a_{2m}  \\
    \svdots & \svdots & \sddots & \svdots \\
    a_{n1}  & a_{n2}  & \cdots  & a_{nm}
  \end{bsmallmatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Output of sample code]

Comment: … as @egreg has pointed out while I was typing my anser. :-)  Consider also mimicking the definitions of `\vdots` and `\ddots`, but with reduced values for the `\raise`s and the `\kern`s (I am going to leave this to egreg as well ;-) .

Comment: OK, thanks! Can I ask why the additional `$...$` is strictly needed around `\ddots` but not `\vdots`? That seems strangely inconsistent to me.

Comment: That’s because `\ddots` expands to a `\mathinner` atom, which requires math mode, but `\vdots` expands directly to a `\vbox`, which is allowed in horizontal mode too.  But as egreg says, for consistency it’s better to add `$...$` around `\vdots` as well.

Answer (score 0):

For information, the package `nicematrix` provides homogeneous tools to construct mathematical matrices with dotted lines, included ``small matrices'' with the key `small`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[small,xdots/shorten=5pt]
    a_{11}  & a_{12}  & \Ldots  & a_{1m}  \\
    a_{21}  & a_{22}  & \Ldots  & a_{2m}  \\
    \Vdots  & \Vdots  & \Ddots  & \Vdots \\
    a_{n1}  & a_{n2}  & \Ldots  & a_{nm}
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]